# Is there a more efficient way to sort this array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an array of a certain user's invites (invites he has received from other users). And I want the frontend to sort these invites by their status. 4 possible categories, expired, completed, accepted and pending. The invites are fetched as objects from the DB. And this is how I sort them. The array `partArray` includes all of the invites and needs to be sorted into `acceptedArr`, `expiredArr`, `completedArr` and `pendingArr`.

```
for(let j = partarray.length-1;j>=0;j--){



           if(partarray[j].userStats[auth.uid]==1 &&partarray[j].inviteStat==1){

             acceptedArr.push(partarray[j].id)
             partarray.splice(j, 1);

           }
           else if(partarray[j].userStats[auth.uid]==-1||partarray[j].inviteStat==0){

               expiredArr.push(partarray[j].id)
               partarray.splice(j, 1);


           }
           else if(partarray[j].userStats[auth.uid]==0&&partarray[j].inviteStat==1){

               pendingArr.push(partarray[j].id)
               partarray.splice(j, 1);


           }else if(partarray[j].inviteStat==2){


               completedArr.push(partarray[j].id)
               partarray.splice(j, 1);


           }


         }



        }
```

As you can see, in order for the invite to be sorted into the acceptedArr it needs to fulfil 2 conditions `partarray[j].userStats[auth.uid]==1 && partarray[j].inviteStat==1` there are different conditions for each category. Is there a way to achieve what I'm doing in a more efficient manner?

Comment: You might consider the native array `.sort()` method

Comment: Do you need to be mutating `partarray` like this? If you just looped through it normally and left it alone, it should work fine.

Comment: Pretty much every programming language (or its standard library) includes an efficient sort method, and that method is written in a way that allows custom sort criteria.

Comment: I thought at first you were grouping users by those four criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just filter them like this?

```js
const acceptedArr = partarray.filter(invite => invite.userStats[auth.uid]===1 && invite.inviteStat===1).map(invite => invite.id);
const completedArr = partarray.filter(invite => invite.inviteStat === 2).map(invite => invite.id);
```

Comment: Yes but as you can see in the code, I'm only storing the field "id" from the invite object. Is there any way I can use array.filter and then store only the "invite.id" field? That would be ideal but I wasn't able to do this

Comment: You can map resulted arrays to get only ids. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid splitting array into 4 categories and use `array.sort` instead.

Here's the implementation with sample data.

```js
const auth = {
  uid: 'test'
}

const partarray = [{
    userStats: {
      test: 1
    },
    inviteStat: 1
  },
  {
    userStats: {
      test: -1
    },
    inviteStat: 0
  },
  {
    userStats: {
      test: 0
    },
    inviteStat: 1
  },
  {
    userStats: {
      test: 1
    },
    inviteStat: 2
  }
]

const evaluateOrder = ({
  userStats,
  inviteStat
}) => {
  // lower value - higher ranking

  if (userStats[auth.uid] === 1 &&
    inviteStat === 1)
    return 1;

  if (userStats[auth.uid] === -1 &&
    inviteStat === 0)
    return 2;

  if (userStats[auth.uid] === 0 &&
    inviteStat === 1)
    return 3;

  if (inviteStat === 2)
    return 4;
}

const sortUsers = (array) => {
  array.sort((prev, next) => {

    const prevOrder = evaluateOrder(prev);
    const nextOrder = evaluateOrder(next);

    return prevOrder - nextOrder;
  })
  
  return array;
}

console.log(sortUsers(partarray))
```

Comment: I realise that splitting not an ideal solution. Your answer is much appreciated, I will surely work on optimising this process and when I do I'll refer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. You can eliminate a lot of that code with a switch statement though, and by moving the common code to the bottom:

```
for (let j = partarray.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

  let el = partarray[j]
  let userStats = el.userStats[auth.uid]
  let inviteStat = el.inviteStat

  switch(inviteStat){

      case 0:
          //do something
          break;

      case 1:
        if(userStats == 0){
           //do something
        } else if(userStats == 1){
           //do something
        }
        break;

      case 2:
          //do something
          break;
  }

    if (userStats == -1 ){
      //do something    
    } 

    pendingArr.push(el.id)
    partarray.splice(j, 1);
}
```